# Open local file in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, url

I am rendering the following simple HTML in a Windows Forms WebBrowser control:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY bottommargin='0' leftmargin='10' rightmargin='0' topmargin='10'>
    <span>Programs</span><br /><br />
    <a href='file:///C:\Temp\prog1.cnc'>Program 1</a><br />
    <a href='file:///C:\Temp\prog2.cnc'>Program 2</a><br />
    <a href='file:///C:\Temp\prog3.cnc'>Program 3</a><br /> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The issue is that the links do not navigate to the file identified in the href attribute.

I can confirm that the `AllowNavigation` property on the control is set to `True`.

Also, the `Navigating` event does not fire when I click the links.

If I change the paths to reference a file on a remote share, everything works as expected, for example:

```
<a href='file://\\servername\Temp\prog1.cnc'>Program 1</a>
```

OR without the `file` prefix:

```
<a href='\\servername\Temp\prog1.cnc'>Program 1</a>
```

Both fire the `Navigating` event.

What am I missing when referencing a local file?

I have tried changing the file path to a public folder to rule out permission issues.
The same app is also writing the files so permission issues seem unlikely.

The files are simple text files which I'm trying to display in the browser control when the links are clicked.

## Code setting the `DocumentText` Property of the browser control:

```
Private Shared Function LoadProgramHtml(ByVal programFiles() As String) As String

    Dim programHtml As New StringBuilder

    If ProgramFiles.Length > 0 Then

        programHtml.AppendLine("<HTML>")
        programHtml.AppendLine("<HEAD></HEAD>")
        programHtml.AppendLine("<BODY bottommargin='0' leftmargin='10' rightmargin='0' topmargin='10'>")
        programHtml.AppendLine("<span>Programs</span><br /><br />")

        For Each program As String In ProgramFiles

            Dim progInfo As New FileInfo(program)

            programHtml.AppendLine(String.Format("<a href='file://{0}'>{1}</a><br />", progInfo.FullName, progInfo.Name.ToUpper))
        Next

        programHtml.AppendLine("</BODY>")
        programHtml.AppendLine("</HTML>")

    End If

    WebViewer.DocumentText = programHtml.ToString()

End Function
```

## Code to handle the navigating event:

```
Private Sub WebViewer_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebViewer.Navigating

    Dim filepath As String = e.Url.OriginalString

    If File.Exists(filepath) Then

        Dim progInfo As New FileInfo(filepath)

        If progInfo.Extension.ToLower = ".cnc" Then

            WebViewer.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
            WebViewer.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(e.Url.OriginalString).Replace(Chr(13), "<br />")

        End If

        e.Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around which will keep me going for the time being but I would still be interested if anyone has an explanation for the behaviour described.

By faking a remote file path, I can cause the `Navigating` event to fire as it did for actual remote files, then in the `Navigating` event, I re-write the path to re-reference the local file as follows:

## Setting Document Text

Change:

```
programHtml.AppendLine(String.Format("<a href='file://{0}'>{1}</a><br />", progInfo.FullName, progInfo.Name.ToUpper))
```

To:

```
programHtml.AppendLine(String.Format("<a href='{0}' target='_top'>{1}</a><br />", progInfo.FullName.ToLower.Replace("c:", "\\faked"), progInfo.Name.ToUpper))
'note the `\\faked`
```

## Handling the `Navigating` event

Add the following:

```
Dim filepath As String = e.Url.OriginalString.Replace("\\faked", "c:")

    If File.Exists(filepath) Then
    ....
```